# Page numbering when multiple sections are added in PhpWord

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I have two sections in my PhpWord and i cannot get it automatically count page numbers in footer and in Table Of Contents.

Is there a way to have page numbers go from 1 to final page number, although i have multiple sections?

```
    $phpWord = new PhpWord();
    $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(9);
    
    $section = $phpWord->addSection([
        'marginLeft' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginRight' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginTop' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginBottom' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'pageNumberingStart' => 1,
        'orientation' => 'portrait'
    ]);


    $landScapeSection = $phpWord->addSection([
        'marginLeft' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginRight' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginTop' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginBottom' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'orientation' => 'landscape'
    ]);
    $landScapeSection->getStyle()->setPageNumberingStart(1);

    $thirdSection = $phpWord->addSection([
        'marginLeft' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginRight' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginTop' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'marginBottom' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(0.5),
        'pageNumberingStart' => 1,
        'orientation' => 'portrait'
    ]);
```